# Firefox Extension absolute URL during cfx run vs cfx xpi?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am very new to developing a Firefox Add-On. My question is:
Is the root path to an asset different when using `cfx run` to debug compared to using the cfx xpi?

So say I have an image file that will be packed inside my extension. To display it, the CSS/HTML will point to the image's URL. I was hoping to use the absolute URL starting with the root. It is able to find the image when I compile the add-on using cfx xpi. But it was not able to find the image in my debug instance when using cfx run.

When I rearrange the directory structure so that the images are relative, using a relative URL is able to find the images in both cfx run and cfx xpi. But I want to use an absolute URL so that my webapp and my Firefox Add-On can share some code.

What's going on? Is this a bug in the firefox SDK? Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what would that absolute url be? Something like `file://path/to/your/project`? Maybe provide some code example of what you're actually trying to call and what fails.

Comment: Permitting the use of an absolute path would have security issues (and cross platform issues). Without jumping through significant hoops, all resources for a Firefox add-on are expected to be contained within the add-on `.xpi` file. I would not be surprised if what you are seeing is the intended behavior (i.e. not permitting you to use an absolute path) with cfx.

Comment: If an image file is packed inside your extension, then prior to packaging the add-on, it would be very rare for you to know the absolute URL (starting at `file://`) for that resource once the add-on has been installed by someone else on their machine. Paths to such resources are what `chrome://myaddon/` URLs are for. Firefox add-on development is geared towards eventually distributing the add-on. What you want to do implies that the add-on will only be used on machines which you control (i.e. where you have defined that the install directory will be outside the profile directory structure).

Answer (score 0):

The path should be the same for cfx run and cfx xpi, what paths are you seeing generated?